# Spark giving error: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131""=="x" was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, apache-spark

for some reason Spark stopped working due error:

> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131""=="x" was unexpected at this time.

I am running Spark on Windows10 in command prompt with admin privileges.

Things that I've tried to fix the problem:

- Removed all files and folders under Spark folder
- re-extracted files from .tar
- re-installed Java and recreated Java environment variables

I am using:

- java version "1.8.0_131"

Comment: I think the JAVA_HOME is not set correctly, export JAVA_HOME as `C:\program/ Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Comment: Should it go with the forward slash in the middle? Tried, but unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 8):

If your Java installation directory has a space in its path name, you should use the shortened path name (e.g. C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6) in the environment variable instead.
Note for Windows users on 64-bit systems
use Progra~1 for 'Program Files' and 
Progra~2 for 'Program Files(x86)'
https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf57/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-701435892.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. The best and the quickest way is to get your Java home out of program files and take it to the path with no spaces in file name.
Ex: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any code, so I'm guessing that you didn't escape your backslashes. `\J` and `\j` are illegal in character and string literals. Just use forward slashes anyway. Also, what's with the odd number of quote marks?

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Comment: I am a bit newbie with Spark still. Where should I take the code from? Config files are untouched now as I reinstalled Spark. I do not know where this error comes from. Number of quote marks is really weird. I tried to play around with the Java environment variable by replacing backslashes with forward slashes but it didn't help. When I use backslashes I can change the folder in Command Prompt by typing cd %JAVA_HOME%.

Answer (score 0):

I removed and created again environment variable "JAVA_HOME -> jdk path", then it worked for me. Note: Restart may be needed.